# How to define a route by using camel-quarkus-jdbc?

Tags: jdbc, apache-camel, quarkus

I am trying to use camel-quarkus-jdbc in my code but am receiving an error:

"Failed to resolve endpoint: jdbc://camel due to: No bean could be found in the registry for: camel of type: javax.sql.DataSource"

There's not much information in the internet about this.
This is the official documentation and there's not much described in it:
https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/latest/reference/extensions/jdbc.html

So here are my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-quarkus-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-db2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And here is my configuration in application.properties:

```
quarkus.datasource.camel.kind=db2
quarkus.datasource.camel.username=some_user
quarkus.datasource.camel.password=some_pass
quarkus.datasource.camel.jdbc.url=jdbc:db2://some_host:5034/some_database
quarkus.datasource.camel.jdbc.max-size=16
```

And here's how I'am trying to send an SQL to the database:

```
    from(platformHttp("/db").httpMethodRestrict(HttpMethod.GET))
            .routeId("test:example:getfromdb")
            .setBody(constant("SELECT * \n"
                    + "FROM SOME_TABLE \n"
                    + "WHERE 1=1"))
            .to("jdbc:camel");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a misnamed property. `quarkus.datasource.camel.kind` should be `quarkus.datasource.camel.db-kind`.

Comment: Thanks, this has solved my issue! I might have copied it from somewhere else because i've read a lot of different articles. At the beginning db-kind was failing because i had to add "quarkus-jdbc-db2" in the dependencies